# Webpack build error: Can't resolve 'stream' and 'timers' etc

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm

I'm trying to build a project using Webpack, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\path\to\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in 'C:\path\to\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol'
```

I've tried adding the following to my Webpack config, as suggested by the error messages:

```
resolve: {
  fallback: {
    "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    "timers": require.resolve("timers-browserify")
  }
}
```

I also installed the `stream-browserify` and `timers-browserify` packages, but the error persists.

I'm using Webpack version 5.64.4.

Here's my full Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',

  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      "net": require.resolve("net-browserify"),
      "tls": require.resolve("tls-browserify"),
      "zlib": require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
      "async_hooks": require.resolve("async_hooks"),
      "http": require.resolve('stream-http'),
      "buffer": require.resolve('buffer/'),
      "process": require.resolve('process/browser'),
      "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
      "fs": require.resolve('fs-extra'),
      "timers": require.resolve("timers-browserify")
    }
  },
  entry: './src/index.js', // or the entry file for your application
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // or the output path for your application
    filename: 'bundle.js' // or the output filename for your application
  },
    module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error? Thanks in advance for your help!